# Transormation of two exponential RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

$X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are IID  exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda=3$. Calculate $X_{1}/X_{2}$.

If $Y_{1}=X_{1}/X_{2}$ and $Y_{2}=X_{2}$ then distribution:
 $$g(y_{1},y_{2})=9\ y_{2}\ exp(-3(y_{1}y_{2}+y_{2}))=9\ y_{2}\ exp(-3y_{1}y_{2})exp(-3y_{2})$$

Then I try to calculate marginal density $g(y_{1})$ but it is impossible (or at least it can take few hours,and many unconventional subsitutions).

Is it even possible to calculate such marginal density or we have to use some "trick" or property of exponential distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just compute the cdf and take a derivative:

$P(\frac{X_1}{X_2} < a) = P(X_2 > \frac{1}{a}X_1) = \int_0^\infty P(X_2 > \frac{1}{a}x)f_{X_1}(x)dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-3x/a} 3e^{-3x} dx = \frac{a}{a+1}$

Take a derivative with respect to a and you have the pdf of $f_{\frac{X_1}{X_2}}(a)$

Comment: Could you explain part "P(X2>1aX1)=∫∞0P(X2>1ax)fX1(x)dx"? I understand marginalization but what is exactly P(X1>X2) ?

Comment: $P(X_1>X_2)$ is just a way to ask what is the probability that the random variable $X_1-X_2$ is greater than $0$. The other part, heuristically, is just saying that the probability that one random variable is greater than the other should depend on how that other r.v. is distributed (and in fact, it does in the calculation above).

Answer (score 0):

Heuristically, if $X_1,X_2$ are independent and have one sign (as in this case) you should expect $f_{X_1/X_2}(r)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(rx) f_{X_2}(x) dx$, because if $X_1/X_2=r$ and $X_2=x$ then $X_1=rx$.

Plugging in the relevant densities in this case gives $\int_0^\infty 9 e^{-3(rx)} e^{-3x} dx$. This integral is of course quite easy to calculate, but can you prove that this formula is correct? (Probably the best way to carry out this proof is to pass through the CDF $F_{X_1/X_2}$.)